# Checking if XML Attributes exist in loop

Tags: php, xml

When looping through the below xml object,  I need to get the data out of each attribute, and if attributes dont exist, move on.  I am not sure how to check to see if @attributes even exists.  Currently, if it doesn't my loop dies.

I have tried:

```
  if(isset($v[0]->user->attributes())){
        ....
  but that gives me a php error:

Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
```

So I am not sure how to check if it exist, if it does i can run through the loop. if it doesnt i can move on...

```
 [server] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 17980
                    )

                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1075159
                                        [default-loc] => 50000
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [license] => high,standard
                                        [password] => aebecf880f2060c31e44f820785e0aa63ea4cc44
                                        [primary] => 50000
                                        [username] => 17980_50000
                                    )

                                [description] => Customer X
              )
         )
    )
     [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14642
                    )

                [user] => Array
                      (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                              [description] => Customer Y
                            )
    )
     [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 24151
                    )

                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1075159
                                        [default-loc] => 50000
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [license] => high,low
                                        [password] => aebecf880f2060c31e44f820785e0aa63ea4cc44
                                        [primary] => 51412
                                        [username] => 17980_51412
                                    )

                                [description] => Customer Z
              )
         )
    )
)
```

Comment: Not related to your issue, but your passwords appear to be hashed with SHA1. Please note that this is **insufficient** for modern security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much this will help you, but when trying to iterate through an XML. I find its best to use recursion instead of looping. Your question doesn't show if you are using a recursive function or a loop but you do say "When looping through..."

If you solve this recursively, you can simply stop and perform your required operation whenever you detect you are at a leaf node that is of type attribute.

This should eliminate any potential null pointer exceptions you may encounter when simply "looping" through the XML.